# Access Violation writing location using CPLEX with VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cplex

I am new to C programming. I'm running CPLEX library in a C++ code using visual studio 2010. I'm getting access violations when performing some actions.

The violation is reported in the function void __cdecl _unlock defined in the CRT file mlock.c. The specific row is LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );.

The error message is Unhandled exception at 0x0f63443b: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xeb43c7c4. My interpretation is that it is a memory related problem but I am not sure. Also, I do not know how to trace the memory block 0xeb43c7c4 in the code.

Below is the call stack:

```
    cplex124.dll!0fdd443b()     
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for cplex124.dll]  
    cplex124.dll!0fdd3bbb()     
    cplex124.dll!0fcd0610()     
    cplex124.dll!0fccfbfd()     
    cplex124.dll!0feb70fd()     
    cplex124.dll!0fede883()     
>   name.exe!_unlock(int locknum)  Line 375 C
    name.exe!_unlock_file2(int i, void * s)  Line 356 + 0x9 bytes   C
    name.exe!printf(const char * format, ...)  Line 68 + 0x10 bytes C
    name.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv)  Line 620 + 0xe bytes    C++
    name.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 278 + 0x12 bytes C
    kernel32.dll!7693ed6c()     
    ntdll.dll!7701377b()    
    ntdll.dll!7701374e()
```

The source for _unlock comes in the mlock.c file as:

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
        int locknum
        )
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}


#ifdef _M_IX86
#pragma optimize("y",on)
#endif  /* _M_IX86 */
```

And source for printf is in the file printf.c as:

```
int __cdecl printf (
        const char *format,
        ...
        )
/*
 * stdout 'PRINT', 'F'ormatted
 */
{
    va_list arglist;
    int buffing;
    int retval;

    _VALIDATE_RETURN( (format != NULL), EINVAL, -1);

    va_start(arglist, format);

    _lock_str2(1, stdout);
    __try {
        buffing = _stbuf(stdout);

        retval = _output_l(stdout,format,NULL,arglist);

        _ftbuf(buffing, stdout);

    }
    __finally {
        _unlock_str2(1, stdout);
    }

    return(retval);
}
```

If I remove the links for concert files in the project property, I get the same error message but in the file tidtable.c, in _CRTIMP PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION __cdecl __set_flsgetvalue() on line: PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION flsGetValue = FLS_GETVALUE;

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your source, especially the `_unlock` method and the code that calls `printf`?

Comment: I've added the sources in the question.

Comment: You have likely corrupted your stack or heap in your code, before you call the library code.  You should look at your code and the "some actions" that you refer to.

Answer (score -1):

Cplex is a commercial solver library.  They likely release several different versions of the DLL you mention to line up with various build types.

Also, libraries of this type usually give you a bit of flexibility in the preprocessor definitions you can define.  See the cplex documentation for details. Mismatched defines can cause errors like this, as can using a runtime that does not support multi threading with a library that does.

I would also suggest looking at GLPK, the GNU Linear Programming Kit for an open source alternative if CPLEX proves problematic.

Comment: Thanks, I have linked CPLEX according to the IBM user guide (http://my.gl.fudan.edu.cn/teacherhome/xlsun/ccqp/c_cpp.html). Also, I have set the run time library to Multi-threaded(/MT). Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @user1372020 so you're using the release-multthreaded-static library version of CPLEX? That addresses what is precisely being referred to in this answer. That may not be right for your specific build. There are, from the doc you linked, other possible options based on your project. I would take a look at those as well.

Comment: Thank, Yes release-multi-threaded(/MT) is what I was using, as you suggested I also tried the multi-threaded DLL(/MD) with its additional directories, but I still get the same error message.